# Última atualização tabela MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

bom dia.

Tenho uma procedure que roda diariamente deletando os dados de uma tabela com dados diários dos clientes do meu sistema e por questões de disponibilidade de dados, às vezes essa procedure é executada mais cedo ou mais tarde.

Gostaria de saber se há uma query que visualize a data da última atualização de uma tabela para que eu possa utilizá-la no PHP para mostrar aos usuários a última atualização realizada dentro do sistema (tabela).

É possível?

Obrigado!

---

Fiz o teste e ele me retorna um valor `null`.

> *Vale salientar que essa minha tabela não acumula dados, ela é deletada e recebe insert de dados do dia em questão.*

Talvez eu não tenha formulado bem a pergunta.

É possível?

Answer (score 1):

Dessa forma:

```
SELECT
    UPDATE_TIME as ultima_atualizacao
FROM
    information_schema.tables
WHERE
    TABLE_NAME = 'nome_da_tabela'
AND
    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'nome_do_banco';
```

Comment: Revise os termos que usou ao setar os valores em `TABLE_NAME` e `TABLE_SCHEMA`. A `query` que o @JasarOrion passou te trará uma listagem, execute ela e veja o que ela trás para conferir os parâmetros.

Answer (score 0):

todas alterações sao gravadas no information_schema do mysql para isso use algo parecido com esta query

```
SELECT UPDATE_TIME, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
FROM information_schema.tables
ORDER BY UPDATE_TIME DESC, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
```

em cima dela vc edita para o que você precisa